# Porque -1 aonde a resposta merece +1?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, voto-contra

Diante a pergunta: [Diferença em meses de data em postgresql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29082/11549), tive o interesse de responder também. Existem no caso do **PostgreSQL** uma *function* que faz um cálculo perfeito referente a pergunta. Só lembrando que nenhum momento quis descredenciar a outra resposta.

Perguntas:

1 - A minha pergunta tinha 1 ponto positivo e agora tem 0, será que falta um crescimento na galera, ou se vota simplesmente por raiva ou simplesmente sem entendimento nenhum voto para falar assim a outra é que é a correta, ou então, vamos detonar essa resposta?

2 - As respostas corretas não deveriam ser utilizadas como referencias e ajuda a contribuir com o repositório de informações verídicas?

3 - Se a resposta tem algum problema, poderia então colocar o porque do voto negativo e apontar o erro para solução futura?

Meus questionamentos tem a finalidade de entender isso, devido a várias outras perguntas sobre votos.

Comment: PS: acho que a tag da sua pergunta deveria ser [suporte](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suporte) e [pergunta-especifica](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%C3%ADfica) e não debate, embora possa ser modificada para direcionar a um debate sobre down votes em respostas. (não acho necessário).

Comment: PS: @Kyllopardiun é um debate! visto que isso é para que todos possam participar!

Comment: Eu voto -1 se estiver de ressaca... bom, é mentira, mas podia ser verdade. É impossível saber, se fossem vários votos negativos até dava pra analizar, sendo só um, pode ser o alinhamento dos planetas ou alguém que não gosta do seu estilo de código... pura especulação...

Comment: @brasofilo menos -1 para você, porque, ressaca quem pode estar é tu !!! tenha um pouco de respeito.

Comment: OMG, não é minha intenção te ofender... só quero exemplificar que -1 pode ser ***por qualquer motivo***. Parece que vc está tentando encontrar justificativas para o voto onde elas não existem. Peace!

Comment: Peace! @brasofilo eu te conhece a tempos. Não me venha fazer politica aonde não existe! e não fala ressaca porque sim me ofendeu!

Comment: Ok, tchauzinho, saindo pela esquerda.

Answer (score 13):

**Não há porque se preocupar, nem o quê fazer.**

Sim, concordo que é chato receber votos negativos, mas não tem porque considerar isso como o fim do mundo. Seja quem for que votou tem o direito de fazê-lo e *não tem a obrigação de justificar*.

Entendo que seu objetivo possa ser que queria corrigir talvez sua resposta. Mas, não há como cobrar justificativa de quem fez isso e por mais chato que seja é só um voto de discordância, não deve ser considerado como nada além disso.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um voto negativo [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23826/8917) e por mais que eu e outras cinco pessoas consideram a resposta válida. Alguém não a considera e isso deve ser respeitado.

Comment: A preocupação é válida sim visto que isso não é democracia então ... !!! Não estou considerando o fim do mundo, mas, o inicio dele! desculpa mas, eu me preocupo sim! se não vira bagunça!

Comment: Sim, é uma democracia. **Todos podem votar**, mas também há o direito do voto secreto, assim como ocorre nas eleições (também democráticas). **Você pode pedir para alguém explicar o voto negativo**. O que não pode é exigir tal comportamento.

Comment: Claro amigo, downvoter é para resposta errada! não para resposta certa, então não justifica! se ninguém levantar a bandeira vai ficar assim pro resto da vida! é errado.

Comment: O problema é que não há como o sistema do SO definir `esta é uma resposta correta e por isso não será possível votar contra ela`. Precisamos de lutar pelo bom senso, da mesma forma que não há sequer como garantir que a pessoa que votou contra irá ler essa discussão no meta. Ou seja poderá continuar a votar contra e sequer se importará com essa discussão.

Comment: Muitas contrariedades então, e muitos fatores que me remete o quanto precisamos crescer. Fica ai a dica votar por votar deveria ser revisto principalmente o downvoter

Comment: Os votos são secretos para evitar perseguição. Justamente para evitar o *Recebi -1 de alguém irei em uma pergunta dele(a) e irei negativar*. Precisamos crescer no nível pessoal, a maturidade desse modelo pode ser vista no [so]; [su] entre outros.

Comment: Parece que você não aceita mudanças então fica ai a dica... aqui é debate de mudanças que pode ou não ocorrer, não seja incisivo no seu contexto, igual eu vi você respondeu a pergunta do outro OP no debate muito bom no que resultou... desculpas mas, parece que você que votou em mim?

Comment: Veja minha aba de reputação, se tivesse votado em você veria que eu teria um `-1` por ter votado em uma resposta, o que não aconteceu.

Comment: Sua reputação não me interessa, eu disse parece...

Comment: Aproveitando minha atual obsessão por dados e gráficos, [não acredito que tenhamos um problema generalizado com downvotes no momento](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/218810#graph), @Maria.

Comment: Ok @bfavaretto. Mas, se atente nisso porque você tem ferramentas muito mais poderosas para observar os dowvoter, essa é minha recomendação.

Comment: @bfavaretto falando em voto realmente caiu e muito hiem !!!